Physical interpretation of reducible but indecomposable reps of the Poincaré group?
As I understand it, there are representations (reps) of the Poincaré group that are reducible but still indecomposable (i.e., cannot be expressed as a direct sum of two subreps). This would be impossible if the Poincaré group were semisimple, but it isn't. [Edit: Actually, it is possible even for semisimple groups, including the Lorentz group, if one does not restrict to finite-dimensional reps.]
Suppose a physical system or quantum field were described by such a rep. What would be the physical interpretation or description of such a system? Maybe something like an "embellished one-particle system," or a "single particle with additional properties that don't make sense in isolation"? Do any such reps actually appear in physics, and if not, are there good physical reasons for disregarding such reps?

Context: I'm trying to figure out why irreducible representations (irreps) are so important and fundamental, and even assumed to correspond one-to-one with single-particle systems. From what I can tell, there are three arguments, but none is very satisfying.

Reducible reps are built up from irreps, so reducible reps can all be understood as multi-particle systems. I think this argument is just wrong, since the Poincaré group is not semisimple. [Edit: Moreover, even for semisimple groups, the argument fails on infinite-dimensional reps, so one should justify why these are not considered.]
Irreducibility is sufficient to guarantee that mass and spin are invariant under Poincaré actions. I don't understand the technical details of this argument, claimed here. But at any rate, the claim is only that irreducibility is sufficient, not necessary, which leads to my question above.
It is just natural or intuitive that single-particle states should correspond to irreps.* I can't really make sense of this argument without knowing the answer to the question I've asked here.

*This seems to be Weinberg's attitude: "It is natural to identify the states of a specific particle type with the components of a representation of the inhomogeneous Lorentz group which is irreducible, in the sense that it cannot be further decomposed in this way." (Weinberg, p. 63)

Regarding your second bullet point: We use the math which correctly models our experimental findings, so I don't see a problem here.

@TobiasFünke That's a good point. But my question might be relevant to theorists considering possible extensions to standard physics, or exploring possible systems that have not yet been created experimentally, but could be.

I found a paper by Lenczewski and Gruber which claims "The interpretation of the finite dimensional indecomposable representations of iso(3,1) then follows easily as a coupling of a finite number of irreducible so(3,1) representations to an indecomposable iso(3,1) representation, with the dimension of the irreducible representations strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.". Not totally sure what that means yet, but I wanted to send it your way because it seems relevant.

@11zaq Nice reference. Actually, I didn't realize until looking at that ref (and other refs cited within that ref) that even the complexified Lorentz algebra $\text{so}(3, 1)_{\mathbb C}$ has reps that are reducible but indecomposable. I forgot that semisimplicity only forbids the existence of finite dimensional reps of this type.

Completely reducible representations are the important ones because unitary representations are always completely reducible.
To see this, note that if $V$ is a unitary representation with an invariant subspace $W \subseteq V$, and orthogonal complement $W^\perp$, then for $|a\rangle \in W$ and $|b\rangle \in W^\perp$, we have that $$0 = \langle a | b \rangle = \langle g \cdot a | g \cdot b \rangle = \langle a' | g \cdot b \rangle$$
where $ | a' \rangle \in W$ by invariance. But that implies $| g \cdot b \rangle \in W^\perp$ because $|a\rangle,|b\rangle$ were arbitrary. Thus, $W^\perp$ is also an invariant subspace, so $V = W \oplus W^\perp$. This argument can be iterated to show that $V$ is completely reducible. By complex conjugating the last two steps above, the same argument holds for anti-unitary representations as well.
So your question becomes equivalent to "What is the physical interpretation of non-(anti)unitary reps of the Poincaré group"? By Wigner's theorem, not much.

Great! I didn't realize unitary was such a significant requirement.

I'd just like to point out that the claim "This argument can be iterated to show that $V$ is completely reducible" is true, but the proof is somewhat advanced in the infinite-dimensional case, as it requires some form of transfinite induction. There's a proof here.

Point taken, you're totally right that the infinite-dimensional case is more subtle. Thanks for the reference!

@WillG. The reference you give has no reference to the literature. Do you know a published reference?

@ArnoldNeumaier Take a look at the reference given as [2] in the linked Wikipedia article: Procesi 2007, Ch. 6, § 2.1. In my version, the theorem is on p. 155. He proves the corresponding result for modules, but I think this is equivalent to the claim in terms of representations.

@WillG: Thanks. I hadn't seen that the References were hidden....

One other wrinkle I just thought of: It is still possible for a unitary rep $V$ to have a non-closed invariant subspace $W$, in which case $V \neq W \oplus W^\perp$. It seems that this rep would be considered reducible in the algebraic sense, but not in the Hilbert-space sense ($W$ would not be a Hilbert subspace). So this would probably not be relevant for physics.

@WillG: I have difficulties understanding the theorem. Where are sums of modules defined? Why is (iii)->(i) ''clear''? There may be uncountably many irreducible submodules, so one needs a measure and an integral, it seems to me. If the answer is not simple, could you please respond by email?

@ArnoldNeumaier The theorem concerns only algebraic sums and direct sums. However, now that you mention it, I think this theorem is not really relevant to unitary reps. The relevant question for unitary reps should be whether the Hilbert space decomposes as (some kind of) direct sum of irreducible unitary sub-representations.

However, there are two notions of direct sum for Hilbert spaces: Ordinary direct sums of Hilbert spaces (which are still defined even for uncountably many summands), and direct integrals (which use spectral theory). I'm not sure which type is appropriate to use in this context, nor whether a result holds that is analogous to the algebraic case. Qiaochu Yuan has claimed here that a similar result holds

''I'm trying to figure out why irreducible representations (irreps) are so important and fundamental, and even assumed to correspond one-to-one with single-particle systems.''
Free systems must be in a unitary representation of the Poincaré group in order that the generators are represented by self-adjoint operators and hence correspond to the traditional observables, 4-momentum and angular momentum.
Reducibility implies that the particle can be decomposed, hence is not elementary. Thus an elementary particle is represented by an irreducible unitary representation of the Poincaré group.
Causality in quantum field theory imposes additional constraints, so that only representations are admissible. where the spectrum of the momentum operator is in the future cone or light cone
Then one generally rules out the continuous spin representations, the most common argument being that these are not found in Nature. But some speculate that they might be candidates for dark matter.
